# How can I tell IntelliJ to not ask to configure PSR-0

Tags: maven, svn, intellij-idea

Upon creating a new IntelliJ project from SVN, it asks the following question:

```
Detect PSR-0 namespace roots: Do you want to configure namespace roots? It can be done automatically or manually at "Project Settings | Modules".
```

If I answer yes, it doesn't find a PSR-0 namespace root. I am not developing with PHP which (I think) is where PSR-0 and PSR-4 would be used.

Is this caused by an active plugin? How can this detection be disabled?

Comment: Yes, it comes from PHP plugin. If you do not use PHP .. then disable that plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by removing the PHP plugin.